# Developer documentation is empty after upgrading to lastest iOS sdk

Tags: ios, documentation

After upgrading to the latest iOS sdk, my developer documentation is is empty. When doing a search, the contents list on the left side bar appears but the main content is empty.  Try to right click and load in browser but nothing happens too. Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after upgrading to xcode 4.5, and I eventually find that it's because the doc set file is not downloaded completely.
Here is how I resolve this:

1. In the xcode preferences -> Downloads -> Documentation, choose "iOS 6.0 Documentation Set", you'll see a brief about this set below. Scroll up this brief a little bit you'll see something like this:

   > Feed:
   >   http://developer.apple.com/rss/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleOSX10_8.atom
   >   Web Root URL:
   >   https://developer.apple.com/library/etc/redirect/xcode/mac/cc4e97/ 
   >   Identifier: com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleOSX10_8.CoreReference 
   >   Installed Location:
   >   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Documentation/DocSets/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleOSX10_8.CoreReference.docset
2. Save the Feed link to somewhere and click the "Installed Location" to locate the broken doc set in Finder. Delete it. You'll see it's gone in the Documentation list.
3. Click "+" to add a new doc set, fill in the feed URL you just saved.
4. Let the download complete and hopefully everything will come back again.